# Google sign in through my iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk

I want to add Google sign in integration to my app.But i want to use Google SDK not using cocoa pods,if any one have used this iOS SDK please give me its steps to login and get user details as i am not getting proper document for this.

I am using Google Sign-In SDK 4.0.1 in that delegate methods are not getting called.

I am using the following structure:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = @"842331483294-ofk2cbhhfjoga35u1575t4hbq9ek87ii.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate  = self;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
     withError:(NSError *)error {
    // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
    NSString *userId = user.userID;                  // For client-side use only!
    NSString *idToken = user.authentication.idToken; // Safe to send to the server
    NSString *fullName = user.profile.name;
    NSString *givenName = user.profile.givenName;
    NSString *familyName = user.profile.familyName;
    NSString *email = user.profile.email;

}
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
didDisconnectWithUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
     withError:(NSError *)error {
    // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
    // ...
}

- (void)signInWillDispatch:(GIDSignIn *)signIn error:(NSError *)error {

}
```

but any of this delegate method is not getting called.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: did you configure your app in google developer dashboard?

Comment: is this issue occurs in  ios 10 ?

Comment: yes,
i have configured my app but using firebase console as in firebase console my project is managed for android so for iOs also that will be same project but only iOs app should be managed and that i have done

Comment: yes this issue occurs in iOS 10

Comment: Go to capability. check wheteher key chain sharing is off or on .if off make it ON

Answer (score 2):

In xcode 8.0 and ios 10 you need to enable keychain sharing in capabilites .

[image]

Comment: Yes,I have done keychain sharing enabled but still not working.

Comment: i am getting 
"Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x11de34998) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x11dc59d38). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined."

Comment: did you handle url scheme in appdelegate ?

Comment: yes i have done that for REVERSED_CLIENT_ID taken from GoogleService-Info.plist.

Comment: and  implement this method in appdelegae ?- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation

Comment: That also i have done, Can any one share me there demo project code? In which Google sign in sdk is used.

Comment: Hello, Everyone
My issue has been solved.
i just for got to call [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn]; 
Thanks all for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my demo code but this is  not in 4.0.1

[Demo code link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-AnQGuLo3chfkFGaTMtZzlRU3hmRWU0XzV4aDR6UWNyX3ZnNmt1Vmp5c0Zpbi1SS2F1eTA)

Comment: Thanks Bharat,
I am looking in this, if anything i have missed to setup.